# Checkboard using Div and PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a check board using div and PHP.

Similar to this: 
[image]

So far I want a div like this:

```
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
```

And then use a for loop to output each box in specified width of box.

Any idea?

Comment: This is called a "chess board" or a "checker board" :-) A "checkboard" is something else.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php). `for` loops allow you to repeat a certain set of operations a specified number of times. By nesting two `for` loops, you can create 8 rows consisting of 8 columns each.

Next, you want alternating black and white boxes, so I've made all the even-numbered boxes black and the rest white.

```
for($row=1;$row<=8;$row++){
    for($col=1;$col<=8;$col++){
        if($row%2 === 0){
            if($col%2 === 0){
                echo "<div class='white'></div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div class='black'></div<";
            }
        } else {
            if($col%2 === 0){
                echo "<div class='black'></div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div class='white'></div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course **you'll need to style your `black` and `white` classes appropriately** (`display:inline-block`).

Once you get familiar with the above, you can probably write neater version like so:

```
for($row=1;$row<=8;$row++){
    for($col=1;$col<=8;$col++){
        if(($col%2 === 0 && $row%2 === 0) || ($col%2 !== 0 && $row%2 !== 0)){
            echo "<div class='white'></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='black'></div>";
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

[image: output]

based on the full code provided by OP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PHP</title>
        <style>
        body{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
        .wrapper{
            width: 400px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .black{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: #000;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .white{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php
            for($row=1;$row<=8;$row++){
                for($col=1;$col<=8;$col++){
                    if(($col%2 === 0 && $row%2 === 0) || ($col%2 !== 0 && $row%2 !== 0)){
                        echo "<div class='white'></div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='black'></div>";
                    }
                }
            }

        ?>
    </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close, but the pattern has to be mirrored in every second row.

Comment: Hm that works, but that if-else is really ugly. You double the code, more or less. Remember the DRY principle. Instead you could add a 1 to the col number in the original condition for every uneven row. That should do the trick. Or you use a ternary operator based on the row number.

Comment: I think it'll be easier to understand. Once you get how this works you can start getting fancy with the conditionals.

Comment: is there a demo of this?

Comment: I would put it in a code block, but server-side code like PHP won't run. It'll probably be simpler to just plonk it in a PHP file and run it on your localhost.

Comment: I use that HTML and incorporate your php but it did not work out.

Comment: I addressed the PHP part of this. I've updated my answer to offer you some hints on how to style your `<div>`s appropriately, but if you're completely lost you should definitely do some research or even ask a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82355/discussion-between-rodel-garcia-and-huey).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, another method, but easy to understand

```
$divs = ['<div class="black"></div>', '<div class="white"></div>'];

foreach(range(0,7) as $i)
{
    foreach(range(0,7) as $j)
    {
        if($i%2==0)
        {
            if($j%2==0)
            {
                echo $divs[0];
            }
            else
            {
                echo $divs[1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($j%2==0)
            {
                echo $divs[1];
            }
            else
            {
                echo $divs[0];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is there a demo for this?

Comment: Thanks I run the code and guess what it did not show up anything.

Comment: This is not a full code, that works as you copy and paste, you need class black and white defined somewhere in html so that, black div is coloured black and white is white square, after that, you need to put this code in your HTML, and modify this according to your needs, this is just to give you idea how to produce 64 square patterns using loop, hope you understand, this will only generate only html markup for divs you have specified. @RodelGarcia

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like this. In this example, you don't have the extra if statement:

```
<div class="board">
    <?php
        for($row=0;$row<8;$row++){
            for($column=0;$column<8;$column++){
                $color = ($row+$column)%2 ? 'black' : 'white';
                echo '<div class="'.$color.'">&nbsp;</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I also added some CSS so the tiles are printed nicely:

```
.white, .black {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.white {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.black {
    background: #000000;
}
.board {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with just pure CSS using the `:nth-child` selector.

### 5 x 5 grid

```css
.board {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.board div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.board div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

If you want them smaller then that is possible by just changing the width and height elements and adding or removing div's.